# Obtaining Query<T>

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Before I use Objectfy3 to get a Query object like this:

```
@Override
public Query<Question> query() {
    return ofy().query(clazz);
}
```

However with version 4,

```
@Override
public Query<Question> query() {
    return ofy().load().type(clazz);
}
```

Is this the correct way to obtain `Query<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Be aware that Query command objects are immutable (they were mutable in v3).

Comment: When you say immutable, do you mean that when the Query<Question> object returned by the query() function, when I apply filters like Query<Question> q = dao.query(); q.filter("foo", foo); then this filter will have no effect?

Comment: In Objectify4, calling q.filter("foo", foo) *returns* a new query which has that filter set, but the original query instance is unmodified.